# Combining two SELECT statements SQL ORACLE 12C

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am trying to combine these two SQL statements into one statements.
First off, it is a database about Airline which consists of 
Route, Passenger, Aircraft, Schedule and Reservation table.

The infant ticket is $50 while the adult ticket is $251.
There are 15 adult and 3 infant in total that flew the route (RTI-005, Kota Kinabalu - Singapore).

Now I am trying to write a select statement that will display the total revenue generated according to the route (Origin/destination) and it will be separated into "adult ticket price" and "infant ticket price" (Which is born between 2015 to 2017) here are the sample of the two select statement: https://i.gyazo.com/755c34da6d58714efbce4a6c7373c563.png

Here are the two select statements:

```
SELECT R.route_id, R.origin "Origin", R.destination "Destination", 
TO_CHAR(SUM(R.infant_ticket_price), 99999999.99) "Infant ticket"
FROM Reservation Re, Schedule S, Route R, Passenger P
WHERE P.passenger_id = Re.passenger_id AND Re.flight_no = S.flight_no AND 
S.route_id = R.route_id
AND P.date_of_birth BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '31-DEC-2017'
GROUP BY R.route_id, R.origin, R.destination
ORDER BY R.route_id;

SELECT R.route_id, R.origin "Origin", R.destination "Destination", 
TO_CHAR(SUM(R.adult_ticket_price), 99999999.99) "Adult ticket"
FROM Reservation Re, Schedule S, Route R, Passenger P
WHERE P.passenger_id = Re.passenger_id AND Re.flight_no = S.flight_no AND 
S.route_id = R.route_id
AND P.date_of_birth NOT BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '31-DEC-2017'
GROUP BY R.route_id, R.origin, R.destination
ORDER BY R.route_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation where you move `WHERE` clause into a `CASE` statement in `SELECT`. And use explicit joins and not implicit as you use which is an ANSI standard introduced 25 years ago.

```
SELECT R.route_id, R.origin "Origin", R.destination "Destination", 
       TO_CHAR(SUM(CASE WHEN P.date_of_birth BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '31-DEC-2017' 
                        THEN R.infant_ticket_price
                        ELSE 0
                   END), 99999999.99) "Infant ticket",
       TO_CHAR(SUM(CASE WHEN P.date_of_birth NOT BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '31-DEC-2017' 
                        THEN R.adult_ticket_price
                        ELSE 0
                   END), 99999999.99) "Adult ticket"
FROM Reservation Re
INNER JOIN Passenger P ON P.passenger_id = Re.passenger_id 
INNER JOIN Schedule S ON Re.flight_no = S.flight_no
INNER JOIN Route R ON S.route_id = R.route_id
GROUP BY R.route_id, R.origin, R.destination
ORDER BY R.route_id;
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the same columns in `GROUP BY`, so you can use only one query.

```
SELECT R.route_id, R.origin "Origin", R.destination "Destination", 
TO_CHAR(SUM(R.infant_ticket_price), 99999999.99) "Infant ticket",
TO_CHAR(SUM(R.adult_ticket_price), 99999999.99) "Adule ticket"
FROM Reservation Re, Schedule S, Route R, Passenger P
WHERE P.passenger_id = Re.passenger_id AND Re.flight_no = S.flight_no AND 
S.route_id = R.route_id
AND P.date_of_birth BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015' AND '31-DEC-2017'
GROUP BY R.route_id, R.origin, R.destination
ORDER BY R.route_id;
```

Comment: The infant ticket is $50 while the adult ticket is $251.
There are 15 adult and 3 infant in total that flew the route (RTI-005, Kota Kinabalu - Singapore)

Still doesn't get the result I wanted, let's take RTI-005 (First record) as example, the infant ticket revenue is $150.00 dollar while the adult ticket revenue is $3765.00 dollar.

I've tried your solutions and it returned the result of adult ticket in different value ($753) which is 3 infant x $50.

Comment: `WHERE` condition differs between both. See `NOT`.